# Why is roof buckling?

Tags: roof

My old roof wasn't  buckling, so why is new one buckling? 
What would you suggest I do , roofer refuses to fix. Roof is 3.5 yrs old.
Thank you.[image]

Comment: Was the old roof removed before this roof was installed? You'd remember because it would've been raining junk off your roof for a half day, and they'd have brought a dumpster.

Comment: Did the roofer replace the roof sheathing?  If so, did the roofer leave gaps between the OSB or plywood panels?

Comment: The buckling seems to be primarily along and above the eave. Can you see signs of a problem with the wood from the underside, along the eaves? In my neck o the woods the sheathing (plywood/OSB) is rarely carried out over the wall to the edge, we would generally use a cedar shiplap starter board there for the eaves.

Comment: I got stuck at "roofer refuses to fix" - that doesn't make sense since that is their business.  There must be more to this story.  Has this become a legal dispute with the roofer who installed it or something like that?

Answer (score 3):

If the roof sheathing was replaced the spacing of the roof sheathing is most likely the issue.

You can check this by going into your attic and checking that there is spacing between the roof sheathing boards (likely OSB plywood)  board to board typically 1/16 , 1/8 to 3/16 of an inch spacing which allows for expansion, this distance varies depending on direction [top-bottom Long side to long side , width side to Width side].  The board might have an installation instruction stamped on it - that would give you proper spacing for those boards. If the board was installed with those instructions on the attic side of the board you will be able to see the directions for spacing of those specific boards from inside your attic  (if all are buckling or only a few - check the ones that are buckling and the ones closest to them).

After verifying the information above - contact another roofer mention your info and get a quote for a repair and his written explanation of what caused it.

After you have the quote; write the original roofer requesting he repair the roof as it was not installed properly (be cordial and let them know another roofer has looked at the issue as well) allow him time to respond 2 weeks is more than enough time.

During this time you can also get a free consultation from an attorney take your info with you, then if your roofer does not respond let the attorney deal with it so you can have another roofer fix it.

Of course sometimes all the original roofer needs is a letter from an attorney on the attorneys letterhead.